# Rails: how to create a default route for specific object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have a User class and   map.resources :users in my routes.

If I create a link

```
link_to @user.name, @user
```

It will somehow automatically create a link to /users/3 where 3 is an ID of the user.
What if I want to create more userfriendly links and identify users not by IDs but by their usernames. So path would look like /users/some_user_name. How do I reassign the default link for @user so I wouldn't need to change all templates?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FriendlyId](http://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem. This is exactly what you want. For example, if you want links look like `/users/username`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_friendly_id :username
end
```

Comment: Thanks it's a good solution, but I need to change it only for "show" action. The rest of actions should keep working with the normal ID. Otherwise, I'll have to change a lot of templates where sometimes I used @user.id instead of just @user

Comment: I believe there should be a way to just reassign default route for @user

Comment: It's easy to add route for only `show` action with `map.show_user 'users/:username', :controller => "users", :action => "show"` and exclude it from REST routes with `except`, but this is an additional headache. FriendlyId is the better practice. Only what you have to do you should disable user registration with usernames like your action's names, for example, `new`. By the way I'm curious why you want to keep `id` in other actions? Just interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

In User.rb:

```
def to_param
  username
end
```